# Faster methods for set intersection

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, multimap

I am facing a problem where for a number of words, I make a call to a HashMultimap (Guava) to retrieve a set of integers. The resulting sets have, say, 10, 200 and 600 items respectively. I need to compute the intersection of these three (or four, or five...) sets, and I need to repeat this whole process many times (I have many sets of words). However, what I am experiencing is that on average these set intersections take so long to compute (from 0 to 300 ms) that my program takes a very long time to complete if I look at hundreds of thousands of sets of words.

Is there any substantially quicker method to achieve this, especially given I'm dealing with (sortable) integers?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to calculate the intersection?

Comment: What are the integers for? What is the maximal integer?

Comment: Can do, though I'd have to shorten it -- so essentially what I'm doing is to retrieve a Collection from the Multimap for each of the words, then sort the collections by frequency, and finally intersect them starting with the smallest two.
I just found another possible bottleneck, though: I was creating a new HashSet for each of the returned collections. Maybe that caused a lot of overhead. Let's see.

Comment: Removing this indeed seems to massively speed up the process, from 13 to ~ 3 hours.

Answer (score 7):

If you are able to represent your sets as arrays of bits (bitmaps), you can intersect them with AND operations. You could even implement this to run in parallel.

As an example (using jlordo's question): if set1 is {1,2,4} and set2 is {1,2,5}

Then your first set would be represented as: 00010110 (bits set for 1, 2, and 4).
Your second set would be represented as: 00100110 (bits set for 1, 2, and 5).

If you AND them together, you get: 00000110 (bits set for 1 and 2)

Of course, if you had a larger range of integers, then you will need more bytes. The beauty of bitmap indexes is that they take just one bit per possible element, thus occupying a relatively small space.

In Java, for example, you could use the BitSet data structure (not sure if it can do operations in parallel, though).

Comment: Say set1 is `{1,2,4}` and set2 is `{1,2,5}`, how would anding a bitset would give the result `{1,2}`, which is the intersection?

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of something like this, but
(a) wasn't sure about which data structure to use
(b) am not confident whether such a bit operation would be substantially quicker than a standard intersection?

Comment: Is there any standard implementation of such a bitmap?

Comment: Yes, in Java you have the BitSet, which has an `intersects` method

Comment: Thanks a lot, though the correct method in this case would be `and()`.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with a bitmap based solution is that even if the sets themselves are very small, but contain very large numbers (or even unbounded) checking bitmaps would be very wasteful.

A different approach would be, for example, sorting the two sets, merging them and checking for duplicates. This can be done in O(nlogn) time complexity and extra O(n) space complexity, given set sizes are O(n).

You should choose the solution that matches your problem description (input range, expected set sizes, etc.).

Comment: +1 I agree, bitmap indexes are good if the elements of the set lie within certain bounds. They do not necessarily have to start low, since your first bit could represent any number.

Comment: But doesn't the usual HashMap-based solution (check for every element of the smaller set) just take O(m), where m is the size of the smaller set?

Comment: The thing with HashMaps is that they are designed for fast access to an element, but not for sorted operations. What @Eran is suggesting is similar to a merge-sort. You would need data structures that are better suited for keeping your sets in order.

Comment: @user1980127 Yes, HashMap will work as well. Note it will take O(n) expected time: building the HashMap for one set and then iterating the other.  It also comes with the usual caveats of tuning the initial capacity/load factor, etc.
Like I said, you should choose what works best (or at least good enough) for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The post http://www.censhare.com/en/aktuelles/censhare-labs/yet-another-compressed-bitset describes an implementation of an ordered primitive long set with set operations (union, minus and intersection). To my experience it's quite efficient for dense or sparse value populations.